# How to subtract two columns in sql present in differnt tables

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
Update TotalItems 
set TotalItems.No_Items_Present = TotalItems.Total_Items - ItemsTable.No_Of_Items 
where TotalItems.Item_Name = ItemsTable.Item_Name
```

My query isn't working. Any solution????

Comment: This depends on the database you're using. MySQL?

Comment: How "not working" ?? Do you get an error - if so: **what** error!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE a SET a.No_Items_Present = a.Total_Items - b.No_Of_Items
FROM TotalItems a INNER JOIN ItemsTable b ON a.Item_Name = b.Item_Name
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - click the check next to your favorite answer among the several provided in order to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL:

```
update ttl 
set No_Items_Present = ttl.Total_Items - itm.No_Of_Items 
from TotalItems ttl
    join ItemsTable itm on
        ttl.Item_Name = itm. Item_Name
```

In MySQL:

```
update TotalItems ttl
    join ItemsTable itm on
        ttl.Item_Name = itm. Item_Name
set tt1.No_Items_Present = ttl.Total_Items - itm.No_Of_Items
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update(
select ti.no_items_present,
       ti.total_items,
       it.no_of_items
   from total_items ti inner join
       itemstable it on ti.item_name=it.item_name)
set no_items_present=total_items-no_of_items
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you would do something like this:

```
UPDATE TotalItems t, ItemsTable i
SET t.No_Items_Present = t.Total_Items - i.No_Of_Items
WHERE t.Item_Name = i.Item_Name
```